# How to create a new keystore in xamarin.android?

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, apk, publish

I'm trying to publish a xamarin.android app. I'm using Visual Studio with Xamarin Android 6, so I followed [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/visual-studio-xa-6.1-and-earlier/). In part 2, it describes how to create a new keystore as shown in the following screenshot (You can see the complete describtion [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/visual-studio-xa-4.2.6-to-6.1/)):

[image]

I don't get where should I place this command. I looked at that keytool link, but couldn't find any thing. I tried cmd, MSBuild Command Prompt for VS2015 and Developer Command Prompt for VS2015, but all of them showed this error: '$' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

In addition to, I tried to create a new keystore using Visual Studio. I went to tools>Android>Publish Android App and I created a keystore and it appeared in path that I specified. Then I went back to that guide and continued from Sign the APK. But there's not any .apk with name and path that I specified. There are just 3 .apk that were before doing all this and don't work.

Now my question is that where should I use that command? In furthermore, I would like to know is there any other way to publish an xamarin.android app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reyhaneh,

[Keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) is an executable provided by the Java SDK. You'll find it in your Java SDK folder, for example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\keytool.exe
```

You can execute it in a normal command prompt. To create a new keystore, open a command prompt with the following line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\keytool.exe" -genkeypair -v -keystore <filename>.keystore -alias <key-name> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me too. If you generate the key this way, it can be directly imported into the Xamarin Archive tool within Visual Studio on Windows. Further you can also run this command to then export out a PEM format file in case you need to send it to Google for them to update/reset your upload key to the one you've just generated. As they require PEM format:

keytool -export -rfc -alias <key-name> -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore <filename>.keystore

Answer (score 3):

From my experience in generating the KeyStore and eventually publishing to google, which worked like a charm.

1. You first have to Archive your Xamarin.Android project by clicking on the Build menu and clicking Archive. If all works fine, this should archive the project but that's not our target. (Also please make sure the App is set to APK in the Android Package Format in the Project Properties. Just in case)
2. When it's complete, click on it and click the Distribute button at the bottom of the archive page.
3. Choose Adhoc
4. Click the Plus button to create the KeyStore
5. Fill out the form
6. Now, click SaveAs
7. Choose any place to put the APK file (we don't really care at this point)
8. Wait for all to be done
9. Go C:\Users"YOUR PC USER NAME"\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android
10. You will see the KeyStore folder. Go into it to see your App folder containing your KeyStore. Please copy the entire folder and perhaps put it in your App source code folder for safekeeping or any other location of your choice.
11. THAT'S IT

---

FOR GOOGLE PLAY STORE PUBLISHING

12. You will need to provide the KeyStore in the Android Package Signing page in the project properties for the Android project. This is very essential as it's required before your app can be uploaded to the play store.
13. Next, change the Android Package Format in the Android Options tab (in the same android project properties windows) to Bundle
14. Now achieve the android project again by clicking the Archive button in the Build menu. This will now create the App Bundle file for Google Play Store. You can click on the Open Folder when done to get your app bundle file.

GREAT!!1
THAT IT...

Hope this helps... It's a pain at times to do all this just to get your app ready for publishing on the plat store or for other reasons.

You may get some additional information from the link below. It may be helpful as it contains some screenshots but it's not as simplified as what I have done above.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows